# django admin styles messed up after update to 4.2.4

Tags: django

I just updated from django 4.1.10 to 4.2.4 and the admin pages styles are messed up. The top of every page looks like this:[image]
I see many posts here and at https://forum.djangoproject.com/ about this same thing, and all the answers are to run `collectstatic --clear` and clear your browser cache. I have done both of these but no joy. I get the same in an incognito window. One interesting data point is that this issue does not occur using runserver only when using nginx/gunicorn. I have verified that all the static files that it's loading are being found. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: My magic ball says you have a customized admin template or stylesheet you might need to update...

Comment: in 4.2 there's a new js file, theme.js, that was initially not being found by the browser (it was looking in static/admin/js). I found that file in django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js and copied it over hoping that would resolve the issue (it didn't). But now I am noticing that when using runserver (where this issue does not occur) it does not try to load theme.js. This is probably a clue.

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes I ran collectstatic.

Comment: I 'fixed' this by copying django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html into my project and editing it. I don't love this solution but it was the only one I could find.